# Different keys on two collections of same document for Document Versioning Pattern

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a C# application where need to track history of documents, so I want to implement the [Document Versioning Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-document-versioning-pattern). However I'm lost on how to do _id on the hist collection.

Suppose my documents look like this:

```
{
  _id : "abc",
  rev : 3, 
  loc : "root"
  dat : {
    ..
  }
}
```

What I tried is two collections, `live` and `hist`. But how can I set the _id on the hist table to be on `{ _id, rev }` or a generated ObjectId? Else trying to insert the next rev for "abc" into hist would lead to a duplicate key error.

Attibutes on the c# class won't work as that would lead to the same _id on both collections.

I also thought of putting them into a single collection but that would complicate querying quite a bit if I need all active documents with loc=root.

I'm a bit stumped here and the article doesn't mention this obvious issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I settled for two properties:

```
_id 
hid
```

When I store in the History table I update the _id field

```
hid = _id;
_id = $"{_id}_{rev}";
```

And when I load I switch them back:

```
_id = hid;
hid = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not use _id as _id on history collection. Each history document can have it's own unique _id

Hist

```
{
  _id: 'own id',  //unique
  ref: '_id of live',
  rev: 3,
  changes: '...'

}
```

Comment: That woudl be a solution indeed but how do I specificy that when I have 1 C# class?

Comment: my apologies, may I know what you mean by 1 C# class. This is related to .Net?

Comment: My application is wirtten in C# (but could be any OO language I suppose) so the schema for the collection comes from that class. I can set the [BsonId] on that class but that would set the same field as key on both the live and hist collections. I don't see an option in CreateCollectionOptions either.

Comment: since this is tag mongodb, i cannot advise u on C#. In mongo however, if the document you updated is eg. `abc`, we can update with `db.collection.updateOne({ ref: 'abc', rev: 3}, { upsert: true })` and it will create a new document in hist collection

Comment: ok updated the question to indicate C# thx

Comment: btw, _id on hist is auto generated when u use { upsert: true }

Comment: ah I could create a derived c# class where I specify another ObjectID field to be [BsonId]. Would need to cast but that could work.

Comment: I work with python and javascript and I don't have issues with handling any mongodb operations, I'm quite sure C# will be able to easily.